# Java запустить файл .class с входящим аргументом

Tags: java, классы, classloader

Есть файл `ServerListener.class`. Он расположен по адресу `D:\`. В нём есть метод

```
public static void cmd(ServerSocket i1) {
    Socket i2 = i1.accept();
    //...
}
```

Как я могу запустить этот класс таким образом, на подобии следующего:

```
try {
    //Class<?> i1 = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass("D:\ServerListener.class - com.myPackage$ServerListener");
    ServerSocket i2 = new ServerSocket(1234);
    //i1.запуститьКоманду("cmd()", с аргументом i2);
} catch (Exception e1) {
    System.out.println(e1.toString());
}
```

Comment: Такое сделать нельзя и ваш метод main будет падать в 100% случаях.

Comment: @Vartlok, изменил вопрос.

Comment: Всё равно нельзя, как вы собираетесь передавать этот параметр?

Comment: Не знаю. У Вас хочу спросить. Как передавать объект?

Comment: Никак, невозможно сделать то, что вы хотите.

Comment: Упс, там опечатка была. пересмотрите ещё раз.

Comment: что-то вроде `Method method = i1.getMethod("cmd", ServerSocket.class); method.invoke(null, i2);` не сработает?

Comment: Последним вариант можете сделать через reflection, вам сверху уже подсказали какие методы посмотреть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я только что проверил, что данный код решает задачу: запустить статический main из класса, лежащего на жестком диске. Пример дан в синтаксисе Java8.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

public class Main {
    public static final String CLASS_FILE_LOCATION = "C:\\tmp\\M.class";
    public static final String CLASS_NAME = "M";
    public static final String[] DEFAULT_ARGS = new String[]{ "arg1", "arg2" };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(Main::runMainFromAntotherClass);
        thread.start();
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void runMainFromAntotherClass() {
        try {
//            Class<?> clazz = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().loadClass(CLASS_FILE_LOCATION);

            File file = new File(CLASS_FILE_LOCATION);
            URL url = file.toURI().toURL();
            URL[] urls = new URL[]{url};
            ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
            Class<?> clazz = cl.loadClass(CLASS_NAME);

            Method method = clazz.getMethod("main", String[].class);
            method.invoke(null, (Object) DEFAULT_ARGS);

        } catch (InvocationTargetException e1) {
            Throwable targetException = e1.getTargetException();
            if (null != targetException) {
                targetException.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Comment: А метод "main(...)" обязательно должен быть в классе "M"?. Просто я его заменил на "public static void cmd(ServerSocket i1)".

Comment: нет, какое название метода в clazz.getMethod пропишете, такое и будет вызываться. Что-то вроде clazz.getMethod("cmd", ServerSocket.class). Это называется Reflection API, если вы изучаете Java, то это одна из первых вещей, с которой стоит разобраться - она дает понимание, как устроен код на самом деле без необходимости читать стандарты.